# Spacing with TikZ and a rank of organ pipes

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, foreach

I'm trying to make a general diagram of a rank of 61 organ pipes -- there are 61 keys on an organ keyboard (32 on the pedals). For reasons of acoustics, pipes are usually laid out with the even pipes on the right (say) and the odd pipes on the left. I'm almost there, but for the odd spacing between pipes 1 and 2. Here is the simple (too simple?) code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,61} {%
        %% Use **either** of the following two lines:
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pipel}{.25*2^((61-\x)/12)}% Longest pipe in the middle
        %\pgfmathsetmacro{\pipel}{.25*2^((\x)/12)}% Longest pipe at the left
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\posf}{ifthenelse(isodd(\x),-1,1)}% Odd to the left, even to the right
        \draw[thick] (\posf*\x/10,0) -- (\posf*\x/10,\pipel)node[above]{\tiny\x};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and this is the output:

[image: Rank of organ pipes]

What have I missed?

Comment: The odd numbers are set an odd number of units to the left of the invisible 0-line, the even numbers an even number of units to the right of the 0-line. Therefore 1 and 2 are separated by three units (1 to the left, 2 to the right).

Comment: I should have thought of that. Doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a `\posf` dependent shift to the placement, as in `(\posf*\x/10-.05*\posf,0)`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,61} {%
        %% Use **either** of the following two lines:
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pipel}{.25*2^((61-\x)/12)}% Longest pipe in the middle
        %\pgfmathsetmacro{\pipel}{.25*2^((\x)/12)}% Longest pipe at the left
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\posf}{ifthenelse(isodd(\x),-1,1)}% Odd to the left, even to the right
        \draw[thick] (\posf*\x/10-.05*\posf,0) -- 
          (\posf*\x/10-.05*\posf,\pipel)node[above]{\tiny\x};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]